# Найти пропущенные звенья в словообразовательной цепочке

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить данное задание:
Укажите в каких цепочках есть пропущенные звенья:
1. мерить->примерить->примерочный
2. лист->безлистный
3. беречь->сберечь->сберегательный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Укажите, в каких цепочках есть пропущенные звенья.

Пропущено здесь:

1. мерить -> примерить -> **пример-к**(а) -> пример*оч*-н(ый)

И здесь:

3. беречь -> сберечь -> **сберег-а**-ть -> сберега-тельн-ый